# How to count no of rows in selected excel file using VB6

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

I am using below code to read excel file:
I want to print only first row data, for that I require to find no of rows in sheet (non blank) .

```
Set xlBook = GetObject(FilePath)
xlBook.Application.Visible = True
xlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
xlBook.Application.WindowState = xlMinimized

Dim irow As Integer

For irow = 2 To 101
    MsgBox xlBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(irow, 1).Value
Next
```

Comment: Are you trying to count only used rows (non empty rows) in excel sheet?

Comment: Yes I want to count used rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I will not recommend `UsedRange`.

Two reasons

1. `UsedRange` will not give you `no of rows in sheet (non blank)` as you want it.
2. `UsedRange` is highly unreliable. If you want to find the last row then see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) . Please note that this will still not give you number of **NON Blank Rows**.

To get the number of Non Blank Rows, you will have to use AutoFilter. Use `<>""` as the autofilter criteria and then use the visible cells rows count to get the non blank rows.

**Edit:**

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705724/how-can-i-use-vba-to-delete-all-columns-which-are-empty-apart-from-a-specific-he)

This post deletes all columns which are empty apart from a specific header. I am sure you can modify it to suit your needs.