# How to use logic 'last row'and 'delete' with the values in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

1. How to use "last row" logic in VBA ?

   ```
   for i = 1 to lastrow
   lastrow = range("C:C").values.End(xlup).rows
   ```
2. How to delete the blank rows where I have some values in the rows?

Comment: Regd your second point. How is it a `Blank` row if you have values in it?

Comment: To find lastrow you may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: And here is the fastest way to delete [Blank Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705724/how-can-i-use-vba-to-delete-all-columns-which-are-empty-apart-from-a-specific-he/10706434#10706434)

Comment: Yet [ANOTHER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195515/trying-to-delete-a-row-if-no-data-in-row-aj) way which will not delete the rows inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
lastrow= cells (activesheet.rows.count, "A" ). End (xlup). Row
```

"A" can be replaced by 1 without quotes and is the column from wich you want the lastrow.